# Google App Engine gcloud app deploy error [5] using Node.js

Tags: node.js, git, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

I've been successfully deploying my node.js GAE web app for months using gcloud app deploy. It's been a month or so since my last deployment and I've made a few updates since then that I want to get out. So I did my usual

```
gcloud app deploy
```

and it uploaded the files and then failed, giving me this error:

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [5] failed to getGaiaID for "<SERVICE NAME WAS HERE"": generic::not_found: Account disabled: 810593457260
```

At first I thought it was a payment issue - but my payment info is up to date. The only major change to the code I recall is that between this deploy and the last deployment, I started versioning the project with git and pushing to github.

Does anyone have any ideas? In particular, is there any reason Git or GitHub .git would interfere with a gcloud deployment?

Thanks

Comment: Your account is disabled. You must solve that problem first. Google Cloud Billing support is free.

Comment: So, oddly enough, my account ended up not being disabled. My last three attempts at deploying all occurred at unsecured network locations (airport, hotel, convention center). Apparently, google gives a disabled account warning when you try to deploy over an unsecure network

Comment: See answer below for more confusion - on my home network, this issue resolved for two deployments, and then suddenly stopped working. It seems almost random at this point if a deployment will go through or not. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, oddly enough, my account ended up not being disabled. My last three attempts at deploying all occurred at unsecured network locations (airport, hotel, convention center). Apparently, Google gives a disabled account warning when you try to deploy over an unsecure network

Therefore the command `gcloud app deploy` will not be successful when performed over an unsecure internet network.

Later, attempting to make a deploy over unsecure networks disabled the project in GAE. Since billing was in good standing, they continued to serve my content (and bill for it) but changes to the service were disabled.

To enable them again, follow [the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#enabling):

> To enable a service account, at minimum the user must be granted the Service Account Admin role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin`) or the Editor basic role (`roles/editor`)
>
> 1. In the Cloud Console, [go to the **Service accounts**](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?_ga=2.40733218.1864408832.1637612128-2037408586.1637612128) page.
> 2. Select the project
> 3. Click the name of the service account that you want to enable
> 4. Under **Service account status**, click **Enable service account**, then click **Enable** to confirm the change.

Other resources:

- [How to understand the service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)
- [How to create and manage service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)

Comment: If you can perform additional verification. Try again after enabling 2FA. Try with a VPN, etc. Sometimes we must work when traveling and knowing the correct solution is important.

Comment: The plot thickens here - I was able to successfully deploy two or three times on my home network - but then (a few hours later) a deploy gave me the same error. So unfortunately, this answer isn't an all-encompassing fix. Still looking for other solutions.

Comment: Edited above with updated information